# Teradata c# Connect with tdwallet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, odbc, teradata

I'm trying to connect using the string connection below, but with errors.

```
using (TdConnection cn = 
new TdConnection(@"Data Source=ip;
    User ID=myuser;
    Password=$tdwallet(mytdwallet);
    Authentication Mechanism=ldap;"))
```

I'm able to conect like that,works :

```
using(TdConnection cn = 
new TdConnection(@"Data Source=ip;
    User ID=myuser;
    Password=mypass;
    Authentication Mechanism=LDAP;"))
```

But the Problem is I'dont wann put my password in the code,somebody knows some solutions to this problem?

> InnerException    {Teradata.Net.Security.TdgssException:
>   TdgssAuthenticationTokenExchange delegate threw an exception.  See the
>   inner exception for details. ErrorCode: -2146233088 Severity: Warning
>   Facility: LoadTdgss ---> Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException:
>   [Teradata Database] [8017] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.
>   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpMessageManager.CheckForError(Request
>   request)    at
>   Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSecurityManager.GetSsoResponseToken()    at
>   Teradata.Net.Security.Mechanisms.ldapSession.AuthenticateAsClientImplementation(TdgssAuthenticationTokenExchange
>   tokenAuthenticationExchange, String credential, String targetName)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Teradata.Net.Security.Mechanisms.ldapSession.AuthenticateAsClientImplementation(TdgssAuthenticationTokenExchange
>   tokenAuthenticationExchange, String credential, String targetName)
>   at
>   Teradata.Net.Security.Mechanisms.Session.AuthenticateAsClient(TdgssAuthenticationTokenExchange
>   tokenAuthenticationExchange, String credential, String targetName)
>   at
>   Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSecurityManager.Action()}  System.Exception
>   {Teradata.Net.Security.TdgssException}

Answer (score 0):

In your project exists a configuration file (it call "App.config"), you should add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionTeradata" providerName="Teradata" connectionString="Data Source=ip;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;Authentication Mechanism=LDAP;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And then in your file code, you can use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionTeradata"]?.ConnectionString
```